# Binomial Distribution on finding the potency of a drug

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

An experiment is designed to test the potency of a drug on 40 rats. Previous animal studies have shown that a $10$-mg dose is lethal $10$% of the times within the first $4$ hours.

**What is the probability that between $2$ and $8$ rats die during the experiment due to the drug?**

My attempt: 
Let $X$ be the number of rats that die in the first 4 hours. 
$$P(2 \leq x \leq8) = \sum_{x=2}^{8}  \binom{40}{x} (0.1)^{x} (0.9)^{40-x}$$

**To make the drug more potent, the company came with a new formula. This reduced the chances of a new drug being lethal to $1$%. The new drug is administered to $10000$ rats. Approximate the *exact* probability that $5$ rats die.**

My attempt:

$$P(x=5) = \binom{10000}{5} (0.01)^{5} (0.99)^{10000-5}$$

Am I on the right path?

Comment: The wording in the second question is odd. I think it should be "the probability that exactly 5 rats die." However you are right.

Comment: 2nd question, you mean $5$ instead of $x$, right ?

Comment: @AhmadBazzi, yes! I made the necessary corrections. But is the set-up right?

Comment: @RHowe, any idea what the exact number is?

Comment: @Lady I've added an answer

Answer (score 1):

In order to calculate the first statement

$$ P(2 \leq X \leq 8) = \sum_{x=2}^{8} \binom{40}{x} \big(0.1\big)^{x} \big(0.9\big)^{40-x} \tag{1}$$

We can utilize some small python script as it is kind of hard by hand.

```
from scipy import stats

# number of rats
n=40
# lethal dose probability
p=.1
# upper bounds
kmax = 8
kmin = 1
# cdf summations
y1 = stats.binom.cdf(kmin, n, p)
y2 = stats.binom.cdf(kmax,n,p)
# differences
y = y2-y1
y
   y
Out[13]: 0.9040309985710783
```

Note the binom.cdf command is

$$ F(x|n,p)  = \sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i} \big(p)^{i} \big(1-p\big)^{n-i} \tag{2}$$

So we to set our limits

$$ I_{1} = F(x|1,0.1)  = \sum_{i=0}^{1} \binom{1}{i} \big(0.1)^{1} \big(0.9 \big)^{1-i} \tag{3}$$

$$ I_{2} F(x|8,0.1)  = \sum_{i=0}^{8} \binom{8}{i} \big(0.1)^{8} \big(0.9 \big)^{8-i} \tag{4}$$
then we find

$$ I = I_{2} - I_{1} \tag{5} $$
there is a 90% chance $2$ - $8$ rats die.

ok..the second one

$$ P(X=5) = \binom{10000}{5} \big(0.01\big)^{5} \big(0.99\big)^{9995} \tag{6}$$

```
from scipy import stats

# number of rats
n=10000
# lethal dose probability
p=0.01
# exact number 
k = 5
# pmf 
y = stats.binom.pmf(k, n, p)
y
Out[8]: 1.968586020940221e-36
```

Wow, startling difference.. I don't think you can do these by hand. You can make rough approximations.

In the last equation you get some rough terms...

$$ P(X=5) = \frac{10000!}{5!9995!} \frac{1}{100^{5}} \frac{99^{9995}}{100^{9995}} \tag{7}$$
Various things will drop out

$$ P(X=5) = \frac{10000\cdot 9999 \cdot 9998\cdot 9997\cdot 9996 }{120} \frac{1}{100^{2} \cdot 10^{3}} \frac{99^{9995}}{100^{9995}} \tag{8}$$

$$ P(X=5) = \frac{ 9999 \cdot 9998\cdot 9997\cdot 9996 }{120} \frac{1}{ 10^{3}} \frac{99^{9995}}{100^{9995}} \tag{9}$$

It just becomes a really small number..this is the exact reason calculators were invented.

Comment: quite startling difference. An exact probability that 5 rats would die would be 1.9686X10^-36. Would that be an exact number?

Comment: I think I messed up this first calculation, I think it is actually 20% higher but it is mainly because of how many rats there are and the difference in probability.

Comment: I did the computation by hand for the first one and had 0.904030995. Which is 90% chance that 2 to 8 rats would die.

Comment: yep, it's fixed..momentary lapse of judgment.

Comment: the other one shouldn't be wrong.

Comment: how do we make conclusion with the second one? What would be an exact number in terms of percentage?

Comment: it's effectively zero

Comment: does this not answer your question?

Comment: well it did. But probability of 0? Meaning the event didnt occur? I am not sure how to draw my conclusion.

Comment: the probability isn't $0$ it is just very small. it still has a non zero probability of happening..like the chance of getting hit by lightning several times in a year.